# Ack — Ignoring multiple directories without repeating the flag

Tags: ack

Is it possible to ignore multiple directories in Ack, without repeating the flag?

e.g. I know the following *works* (i.e. setting multiple flags):

```
ack --ignore-dir=install --ignore-dir=php 'teststring'
```

I was hoping that I could separate directories with commas, like I can do with the extensions as follows:

```
ack --ignore-file=ext:css,scss,orig 'teststring'
```

However, the following comma separated ignore flag doesn't work:

```
ack --ignore-dir=install,php 'textstring'
```

Is it possible to use some short-hand equivalent, so I don't have to repeatedly type out the --ignore-dir flag?

Answer (score 56):

It's actually similar to how you would specify the include patterns for `grep`:

`ack <term> --ignore-dir={dir_a,dir_b}`

However, This format does not work with a single directory. So

`ack <term> --ignore-dir={log}`

will not work.

Comment: Note that the {} syntax causes a bash-expansion - it's not specific to ack.

Try this at your command line: 

`echo this is cool{1,2}`

Comment: It's also important to point out that because brace expansion is a bash-specific feature, you won't be able to take advantage of it in your `.ackrc` file. Instead you will need to list out each `--ignore-dir=` option individually.

Comment: I found that spacing between the dir names matters: `ack <term> --ignore-dir={dir_a,dir_b}` works but `ack <term> --ignore-dir={dir_a, dir_b}` doesn't

Answer (score 24):

Since you're using ack 2, you can put `--ignore-dir=install` and `--ignore-dir=php` in a .ackrc file in the root of your project.  Then, every ack invocation in that tree will use those flags.

Answer (score 18):

So to ignore single directory use

```
ack <term> --ignore-dir=dir_a
```

and to ignore multiple directories use

```
ack <term> --ignore-dir={dir_a,dir_b}
```

Comment: note: don't put space between multiple directories and comma

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to select those directories to exclude with a regular expression in `-G` option complemented with the option `--invert-file-match`. Based in your question, something like the following:

```
ack -a -G 'install|php' --invert-file-match 'textstring' .
```

Comment: Interesting, but I don't think this is viable in Ack 2. I get the following message:  
`Option '-a' is not valid in ack 2
This is because we now have -k/--known-types which makes it only select files
of known types, rather than any text file (which is the behavior of ack 1.x).
You may have options in a .ackrc, or in the ACKRC_OPTIONS environment variable.
Try using the --dump flag`

Comment: @Birei's solution only works on ack 1.x.  The -a and -G flags have been removed in ack 2 in favor of the -x flag.